# Robot keys not working when using it after implicit wait

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Robot keys not working when using it after implicit wait. If I use thread.sleep instead of implicit sleep the same code working fine. But it is not best practice to use thread.sleep. So give me a solution for this problem.

```
searchbox.sendKeys(sFirstName);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Utils.keyEnter();
```

The code in Utils package is:

```
public static void keyEnter() throws Exception
{
    Robot r = new Robot();
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
}
```

Comment: But what is the usability of `implicitlyWait` just before invoking `keyEnter()`?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two entirely different testdrivers. Selenium Webdriver and `java.awt.Robot` which is hardly a good idea. The `driver` object does not know anything about the `robot` object and vice versa. This means that calling an implicit wait on driver, does not affect the robot object at all.

Also, note that the empty constructor on `java.awt.Robot`

> Constructs a Robot object in the coordinate system of the primary
>   screen.

And the primary screen in your case is most probably not the browser window the driver object operates on. That is why nothing seems to happen.